# Power Bi dashboard with data entry

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-datasource

It is possible using powerbi pro, to publish online a dashboard that allows a user to either:

1) do data entry (maybe a text box in the UI or entering a table in the data model), and that data would be use only in his or her dashboard?

2) do data entry and send data back to the source of that dashboard (a source like a SQL)?

Or all is only possible by incluiding in the powerbi a power app that does does things.
Thanks!

Comment: One solution is described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/desktop-enter-data-directly-into-desktop But I think that is a general problem - how to combine reports with new data. Suggestions how to approach this would be really appreciated and needed ;-). (There are Suggestion like using a separate File etc. ; but that is way too complicated; as it has to be synchronized with the structure of the actual report.)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to do that. This is absolutely not the purpose of a solution like Power BI.

Even with embed apps or custom apps, **PBI isn't designed** to offer these kinds of possibilities.

Comment: Hi! this might be the solution https://powerapps.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/powerbi-powerapps-visual/

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely not, that's not Power Bi's purpose and I wouldn't personally advise such a feature, but if you already have pre-defined entries, I would set those in my table as fields(s) and use Slicers as selection(entry) for the user, if user selects a predefined entry, it will automatically change the charts.